# Problematic accents with MYSQL DATE_FORMAT french / français month and day names via UDF

Tags: mysql, date

I created an UDF to extend DATE_FORMAT function to get French month and day names.

I replace `%a`, `%b`, `%W` and `%M` separately with right word.
I use a CASE statement to convert English to French word, and then replace the format string tag with found word.

It works fine.

```
delimiter |
/*DROP FUNCTION DATE_FORMAT_FR*/
|
CREATE FUNCTION DATE_FORMAT_FR (dt DATETIME, f VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(16);
    /*short day name*/
    IF INSTR(f, '%a') >= 0 THEN
        SET name = CASE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%a')
            WHEN 'Mon' THEN 'Lun'
            WHEN 'Tue' THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN 'Wed' THEN 'Mer'
            WHEN 'Thu' THEN 'Jeu'
            WHEN 'Fri' THEN 'Ven'
            WHEN 'Sat' THEN 'Sam'
            WHEN 'Sun' THEN 'Dim'
            ELSE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%a')
            END;
            /*replace in source format string*/
            SET f = REPLACE(f, '%a', name);
    END IF;
    /*long day name*/
    IF INSTR(f, '%W') >= 0 THEN
        SET name = CASE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%W')
            WHEN 'Monday' THEN 'Lundi'
            WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 'Mardi'
            WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 'Mercredi'
            WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 'Jeudi'
            WHEN 'Friday' THEN 'Vendredi'
            WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 'Samedi'
            WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 'Dimanche'
            ELSE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%W')
            END;
            /*replace in source format string*/
            SET f = REPLACE(f, '%W', name);
    END IF;
     /*short month name*/
    IF INSTR(f, '%b') >= 0 THEN
        SET name = CASE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%b')
            WHEN 'Jan' THEN 'Jan'
            WHEN 'Feb' THEN 'Fév'
            WHEN 'Mar' THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN 'Apr' THEN 'Avr'
            WHEN 'May' THEN 'Mai'
            WHEN 'Jun' THEN 'Juin'
            WHEN 'Jul' THEN 'Juil'
            WHEN 'Aug' THEN 'Août'
            WHEN 'Sep' THEN 'Sept'
            WHEN 'Oct' THEN 'Oct'
            WHEN 'Nov' THEN 'Nov'
            WHEN 'Dec' THEN 'Déc'
            ELSE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%b')
            END;
            /*replace in source format string*/
            SET f = REPLACE(f, '%b', name);
    END IF;
    /*long month name*/
    IF INSTR(f, '%M') >= 0 THEN
        SET name = CASE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%b')
            WHEN 'Jan' THEN 'Janvier'
            WHEN 'Feb' THEN 'Février'
            WHEN 'Mar' THEN 'Mars'
            WHEN 'Apr' THEN 'Avril'
            WHEN 'May' THEN 'Mai'
            WHEN 'Jun' THEN 'Juin'
            WHEN 'Jul' THEN 'Juillet'
            WHEN 'Aug' THEN 'Août'
            WHEN 'Sep' THEN 'Septembre'
            WHEN 'Oct' THEN 'Octobre'
            WHEN 'Nov' THEN 'Novembre'
            WHEN 'Dec' THEN 'D\351cembre'
            ELSE DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%M')
            END;
            /*replace in source format string*/
            SET f = REPLACE(f, '%M', name);
    END IF;
    /*returns standard conversion*/
    RETURN DATE_FORMAT(dt, f);
END
```

But I have a problem with accents:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT_FR('2000-02-01', '%a %W %b %M')
> Mar Mardi F?v F?vrier
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that modifying the stored proc with phpMyAdmin UI, just revalidating it, no more accent problem appears...
So strange.